# Articles matching query does not exist

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I have just started working in Django. My problem in addressing with slug
I get an error when sending a request to Slug.

This is my error: `Articles matching query does not exist.`

I also get an error when migrate.

This is my error:
`django.db.utils.OperationalError:table "bloges_category" already exists`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.text import slugify

    class Articles(models.Model):
        Writer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
        Title = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
        Body = models.TextField()
        Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='articles')
        Time = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, auto_now_add=True)
        Update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    
    def save(
            self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
        self.slug = slugify(self.Title)
        super(Articles, self).save()
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("bloges:articles_detail", args=[self.slug])
```

my view:

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
    from bloges.models import Articles
    
    
    def post(request, slug):
        articles = Articles.objects.get(slug=slug)
        return render(request, 'bloges/post-details.html', {"postartic": articles})
```

my urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'bloges'
urlpatterns = [
    path("post/<slug:slug>", views.post, name="articles_detail")
]
```

Error after sending request:
`Articles matching query does not exist.`

Comment: What does your `Articles` model look like? And please show the `view` you are using when the error occurs.`bloges:articles_detail`

Comment: Did you manually migrate or created tables. Can you show the list and details of the migration files regarding the `Articles` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get an error when sending a request to Slug It is my error: Articles matching query does not exist.

This occurs based on your posted view called `post` not having a URL param named `slug` that matches the call in your view here: `articles = Articles.objects.get(slug=slug)`.

This errors out because you use `get()`, which throws an error if the object searched for is not found. A common solution would be to use `get_object_or_404(Articles, slug=slug)`, which would throw an `HTTP 404` when the object is not found or to `filter`, i.e. `articles = Articles.objects.filter(slug=slug)` in which case if the variable `articles` is not available (i.e. `if not articles`, `None`, or `Articles.objects.none()`, you do what you wish.

Notice your URL param here:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("post/<slug:slug>", views.post, name="articles_detail")
]
```

Which likely calls a URL like: `http://localhost:8000/post/foo`

Where `foo` is not a `slug` found in `Articles` here: `Articles.objects.get(slug='foo')`

> And I get an error when migrate It is my error: django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "bloges_category" already exists

We need to see how your migrations are, and your current DB structure. Overall this error is stating you are running a migration that cannot complete because it is trying to create a table that is already there.

My first thought is that you accidentally deleted your migration files and re-ran `makemigrations`, or you removed your data from your migration table in the DB. But without more info it is hard to tell.